# How do I access ::content elements in Polymer

Tags: polymer

Is it possible to access an element in the "content" area in Polymer?

Let me show an example:

```
<my-element>
  <my-sub-element1></my-sub-element1>
  <my-sub-element2></my-sub-element2>
</my-element>
```

I would like to let my-element to fetch some data to from a rest service using `iron-ajax`, and then display some content in `my-sub-element1` and `my-sub-element2`. Is this possible without transferring the data through properties? my-sub-element1 and 2 should only be used within the context of my-element.

I tried to do a `document.querySelector(":host ::content")`, but it returned null so I guess that is not the way to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to supplement the other potentially correct answers with more details and a demo...

#### `Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('my-sub-element')`

While this method would work in your example use case, it would break if your container element were wrapped in another container, as demonstrated below. Here, `my-element` would not find any elements with `querySelectorAll('my-sub-element1')` (although `my-element-wrapper` would).

Further, this limits future extensibility of your element (e.g., by a third party who cannot modify the original element), which might not be an immediate concern for you.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-element-wrapper>
    <my-sub-element1></my-sub-element1>
    <my-sub-element2></my-sub-element2>
  </my-element-wrapper>

  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        ready: function() {
          var el = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('my-sub-element1');
          console.log('my-element > my-sub-element1:',
                      'length=' + el.length,
                      'element=' + (el.length > 0 ? el[0].tagName : "''"));
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-sub-element1">
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-sub-element1' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-sub-element2">
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-sub-element2' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-element-wrapper">
    <template>
      <my-element>
        <content></content>
      </my-element>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-element-wrapper' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sorike/edit?html,console)</sup>

#### [`Polymer.getContentChildren()`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/acdfc1e/src/standard/utils.html#L195)

This method gets the distributed child elements from your container element's `<content>`, which indeed gets you closer to a flexible solution because a wrapper container (like in the previous example) would not change its results.

However, this gets *all* distributed children, so it would be inconvenient (and perhaps even inefficient) if you were only interested in a subset.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-element-wrapper>
    <my-sub-element1></my-sub-element1>
    <my-sub-element2></my-sub-element2>
  </my-element-wrapper>

  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        ready: function() {
          var el = this.getContentChildren().filter(function(item) {
            return item.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'my-sub-element1';
          });
          console.log('my-element > my-sub-element1:',
                      'length=' + el.length,
                      'element=' + (el.length > 0 ? el[0].tagName : "''"));
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-sub-element1">
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-sub-element1' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-sub-element2">
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-sub-element2' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-element-wrapper">
    <template>
      <my-element>
        <content></content>
      </my-element>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-element-wrapper' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/celumi/edit?html,console)</sup>

#### [`Polymer.queryAllEffectiveChildren()`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/acdfc1e/src/standard/utils.html#L160)

This method combines the two solutions above by fetching specific distributed children by a CSS selector. (It also seems to [perform better](http://jsbin.com/petacu/edit?html,console) than the other two. *I'm not a JS perf expert, so those results could be inaccurate due to bad implementation.*)

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-element-wrapper>
    <my-sub-element1></my-sub-element1>
    <my-sub-element2></my-sub-element2>
  </my-element-wrapper>

  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        ready: function() {
          var el = this.queryAllEffectiveChildren('my-sub-element1');
          console.log('my-element > my-sub-element1:',
                      'length=' + el.length,
                      'element=' + (el.length > 0 ? el[0].tagName : "''"));
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-sub-element1">
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-sub-element1' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-sub-element2">
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-sub-element2' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-element-wrapper">
    <template>
      <my-element>
        <content></content>
      </my-element>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-element-wrapper' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/boqefu/1/edit?html,output)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think that Günter's answer is half correct. Although selecting child elements will work, if you were to use the `<content/>` tag you could prefer selecting only distributed nodes only. I think it's what more closely relates to the `::content` selector.

Here's the snippet from Polymer [documentation pages](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#light-dom-children):

```
<dom-module id="simple-content">
  <template>
    <content id="myContent"></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'simple-content',
      ready: function() {
        var distributed = this.getContentChildren('#myContent');
        console.log(distributed.length);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```